# Using sed to pad-right a number in a CSV

Tags: sed

I have thousands of lines that look like this:

```
e0f186cf-c34d-42e9-b8a9-9b9cf1f304e7,TotalNumberOfHandledConnectionsOrSessions,TotalNumbe1211008586,1457343000,179.00
```

The column before last is a timestamp. The issue is that it's in seconds, where I need it in milliseconds.

So I'd like to right pad that number with 000.

BUT - it's possible one day the lines will have the milliseconds in them, so shouldn't add 000 in that case.

I tried using a few examples on this site with sed but none worked.

Comment: I notice everyone talking about 10 digits. Where are they getting that? Is it 100% of the time 10 digits? Is there any other way to determine that it is in seconds vs. milliseconds? The reason I ask is the value in that field could be 1 to infinite digits, with no way to tell if they are seconds (and need the 000 added) or milliseconds (which need nothing done).

Comment: @KipK Well, it matches the Unix epoch time of a few days ago, so the assumption is that the other time stamps are epoch time, too. It has had ten digits since September 2001, and will have for quite some time. But yes, this assumption might have gone too far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/,\([0-9]\{10\}\),\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)$/,\1000,\2/'
```

This matches a pattern of:

1. comma,
2. exactly 10 digits,
3. comma,
4. some number of digits,
5. a period (escaped),
6. some number of digits,
7. the end of the line

and replaces it with:

1. comma,
2. the 10-digit number (backreferenced by `\1`),
3. three zeroes,
4. comma,
5. the last field, backreferenced by `\2`.

Answer (score 1):

With (GNU) `awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS="," } { if ( length($4)=10 ) { $4=$4"000" ; print $0 } else print $0 }' file
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN { FS="," ; OFS="," }`: in the beginning set the input (`FS`) and output (`OFS`) field separators as comma
- if fourth column has a length of 10 ad three zeros to it and print all
- else just print all